# Could it be an Nginx bug when using regex?

Tags: nginx

I'm cleaning up our configuration so I thought of using regex since I'll be able to remove tons of lines. I'm wondering why the new rule is not working properly or works differently.

The rule below is currently in our dev, stage and prod. It works pretty well. We have many rules that looks like this but the second path is what varies.

```
location /app/sss/cifs/ {
  proxy_pass http://int-svr/sss/s3/dev/app/sss/cifs/;
}
```

I added a new rule(shown below) and I commented out the above

```
location ~ ^/app/(...)/cifs(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://int-svr/$1/s3/dev/app/$1/cifs$2;
}
```

When using the original rule, and my http call is `http://localhost/app/sss/cifs`, I am able to see the page. However, if I use the new rule which uses regex, the url that I typed on my browser will change after visiting the page and I'll get a 404. The url will become `http://localhost/sss/s3/dev/app/sss/cifs`. It's weird that the value on the proxy_pass is disclosed.

Btw, if I'm using the regex rule and my call is `http://localhost/app/sss/cifs/`, it will work. The difference is that this link has a trailing slash. In old rule, both http requests with or without trailing slash, it works.

Any ideas?

Basically, I want the behavior of my original rule but using regex.

Comment: what about `location ~ ^/app/(.)/cifs(.*)` ?

Comment: why only a single dot? I mean, the character there will always be 3 characters

Comment: yep, test it ;)

Comment: I actually use this, return 200 "http://int-svr/$1/s3/dev/app/$1/cifs$2" and the output is correct but it becomes weird when proxy_pass is used

Comment: ok, I'll test your regex

Comment: It didn't work. I got a 404 Check this out - http://imgur.com/a/zVFWN

Comment: on access.log, this is what it logged - 172.20.49.163 - - [22/Jul/2016:02:16:20 +0000] X-Forward-Scheme:http   X-Forward-For:192.168.203.83, 172.20.49.163   request: GET /app/sss/cifs HTTP/1.1   cookies: -   status-code: 404

Comment: What is the exact url you are typing, and what is the exact url you are trying to proxy ?

Comment: It's above on my post. Those are the exact links but internal to our network

Comment: I can access the other server using curl and I am able to get a file

Comment: `location ~ ^/app/(...)/cifs(.*)` then `proxy_pass http://int-svr/$1/s3/dev/app/$1/cifs$2/` ?

Comment: I restored my old rule and captured the traffic. I put the new rule then captured the traffic. The nginx response for on /sss/s3/dev/app/sss/cifs using GOOD rule, I get a 200 OK. But the response when using the regex rule on that kind of path, I get a 404

Comment: So I guess the problem is that this rule `location ~ ^/app/(...)/cifs(.*) {` or this `location ~ ^/app/(.*)/cifs(.*) {` is not used when request is `/sss/s3/dev/app/sss/cifs` I think that's the culprit. It's because `dev` string is not in my rule. However, using the original rule, the proxy_rule works well and I don't have a rule that has `dev` in location

Comment: I give up. I'll just use the original rule. The confusing thing is that why is Nginx giving my browser the path that is in proxy_pass. I think that's a bug

Comment: I finally figured it out. The caret was the culprit. The backend server responded with a different path that didn't start with /app. So that rule got ignored. Removing the caret, the rule was used again.

Comment: please write an answer yourself and add the solution, so anybody having the same problem gets a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues in your question.

The prefix location (your first rule) and the regex location (your second rule) have different evaluation orders. So it is easy to replace a prefix location with a regex location and find that its precedence order within the configuration file has changed. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The second problem is that your regex rule accepts URIs that finish after the `.../cifs` sequence (i.e. without a trailing `/`), whereas the original rule prevents it.

So,

In the case of the first rule, when presented with `/app/sss/cifs`, `nginx` will issue a redirect and add a trailing `/` (either explicitly or implicitly).

In the case of the second rule, this URI gets passed upstream, which also redirects, but with the wrong result.

You could try protecting the upstream by modifying your regex and adding a trailing `/` to `cifs`:

```
location ~ ^/app/(...)/cifs(/.*) { ... }
```

I have placed in inside the capture so that the `rewrite` statement is the same.

If this breaks the `/app/sss/cifs` URI, you could explicitly add a trailing `/`, bu adding a new rule to take care of that specific case:

```
location ~ ^(/app/.../cifs)$ { return 302 $1/; }
```

Comment: I got it working last night. I mentioned it above. The problem was the caret. I had to remove it. It was the S3 bucket web server that was prepending the path to the original path I submitted.